# Broadleaf Commerce Email Java Config

Tags: java, spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce

Using Broadleaf version 5.2 where all / most configs were switched to java based. After attempting to configure email in CoreEmailConfig.java by uncommenting the blMessageCreator bean definition and adding my own smtp server settings, I can succesfully send emails, however have noticed two issues:

1) ThymeleafMessageCreator seems to have been removed from version 5.x, I can't find a description in release notes or elsewhere for the reason. I would prefer to use Thymeleaf email templates, I can add my own class back and it works ok but I still face the second issue, so was wondering if there was another reason to remove it?

2) Regardless of which EmailInfo bean the BLC framework tries to inject (i.e. blRegistrationEmailInfo, blForgotPasswordEmailInfo etc...), it seems to always inject the last one in the CoreEmailConfig.java file. In the demo site the last one is blReturnConfirmationEmailInfo. Is this an issue encountered by others in version 5.x or 5.2 specifically with the spring boot and java configs?

Below is CoreEmailConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class CoreEmailConfig {
    /**
     * A dummy mail sender has been set to send emails for testing purposes only
     * To view the emails sent use "DevNull SMTP" (download separately) with the following setting: 
     *   Port: 30000
     */
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender blMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        sender.setHost("");
        sender.setPort(587);
        sender.setProtocol("smtp");
        sender.setUsername("");
        sender.setPassword("");
        Properties javaMailProps = new Properties();
        javaMailProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        javaMailProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        javaMailProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.timeout", "25000");
        sender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProps);
        return sender;
    }

    /**
     * Uncomment this bean to send real emails
     */
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public MessageCreator blMessageCreator(@Qualifier("blEmailTemplateEngine") TemplateEngine tlTemplateEngine, @Qualifier("blMailSender") JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        return new ThymeleafMessageCreator(tlTemplateEngine, mailSender);
    }

//    @Bean
//    @Autowired
//    public MessageCreator blMessageCreator(@Qualifier("blMailSender") JavaMailSender mailSender) {
//        return new NullMessageCreator(mailSender);
//    }

    @Bean
    public EmailInfo blEmailInfo() {
        EmailInfo info = new EmailInfo();
        info.setFromAddress("");
        info.setSendAsyncPriority("2");
        info.setSendEmailReliableAsync("false");
        return info;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmailInfo blRegistrationEmailInfo() {
        EmailInfo info = blEmailInfo();
        info.setSubject("You have successfully registered!");
        info.setEmailTemplate("register-email");
        return info;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmailInfo blForgotPasswordEmailInfo() {
        EmailInfo info = blEmailInfo();
        info.setSubject("Reset password request");
        info.setEmailTemplate("resetPassword-email");
        return info;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmailInfo blOrderConfirmationEmailInfo() {
        EmailInfo info = blEmailInfo();
        info.setSubject("Your order with The Heat Clinic");
        info.setEmailTemplate("orderConfirmation-email");
        return info;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmailInfo blFulfillmentOrderTrackingEmailInfo() {
        EmailInfo info = blEmailInfo();
        info.setSubject("Your order with The Heat Clinic Has Shipped");
        info.setEmailTemplate("fulfillmentOrderTracking-email");
        return info;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmailInfo blReturnAuthorizationEmailInfo() {
        EmailInfo info = blEmailInfo();
        info.setSubject("Your return with The Heat Clinic");
        info.setEmailTemplate("returnAuthorization-email");
        return info;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmailInfo blReturnConfirmationEmailInfo() {
        EmailInfo info = blEmailInfo();
        info.setSubject("Your return with The Heat Clinic");
        info.setEmailTemplate("returnConfirmation-email");  
        return info;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) ThymeleafMessageCreator seems to have been removed from version 5.x, I can't find a description in release notes or elsewhere for the reason. I would prefer to use Thymeleaf email templates, I can add my own class back and it works ok but I still face the second issue, so was wondering if there was another reason to remove it?

This was changed in 5.1 when Thymeleaf 3 support was added,  the details are in the 5.0 to 5.1 Migration Guide,  more specifically here:  [https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/migration-notes/5.1-thymeleaf-migration](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/migration-notes/5.1-thymeleaf-migration#)

Note that it also seems that in the Demo project, that the dependency for Thymeleaf Presentation is not in the POM file for the Core project, you may need to add it yourself if you wish to leave the EmailConfig in the Core module.

> 2) Regardless of which EmailInfo bean the BLC framework tries to inject (i.e. blRegistrationEmailInfo, blForgotPasswordEmailInfo etc...), it seems to always inject the last one in the CoreEmailConfig.java file. In the demo site the last one is blReturnConfirmationEmailInfo. Is this an issue encountered by others in version 5.x or 5.2 specifically with the spring boot and java configs?

Remove the @Bean annotation from the blEmailInfo() method, it is causing the Reuse of the same EmailInfo object in all the  bl*EmailInfo methods, rather than using a new object.

<strike>@Bean</strike>

```
public EmailInfo blEmailInfo() {
    EmailInfo info = new EmailInfo();
    info.setFromAddress("");
    info.setSendAsyncPriority("2");
    info.setSendEmailReliableAsync("false");
    return info;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. Looked into those, as a result changed message creator to BroadleafThymeleaf3MessageCreator all good there. Second issue also resolved